# Jenkins CLI download fails with 500 Error or 503 Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am using an EC2 instance to setup Jenkins. In the EC2 instance, I bootstrap the following script to download the Jenkins CLI in my EC2 instance.

```
sudo wget http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
```

But when this command executes I receive the following error

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
>   ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.

I googled and found that it might be due to Jenkins is bootstrapping so for that I added following code in the script to wait for the Jenkins to start.

```
 function jenkinsCreationWait () {
   echo "Jenkins Creation Wait"
   while ! test -f "/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword"; do
    sleep 5
    echo "Jenkins is booting, please wait..."
   done
   echo "End"
}
```

I placed this code before executing the

```
sudo wget http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
```

After receiving the error during bootstrap, I SSH into EC2 instance and the tried executing the above command I received 500

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
>   Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Server Error
>   ERROR 500: Server Error.

Although this was working fine some hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using user data. Here is a shell script to wait until you get a 200 code

```
while [[ "$(curl --insecure -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar)" != "200" ]]; do sleep 15; done
wget http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
```

reference [wait for http 200](https://gist.github.com/rgl/f90ff293d56dbb0a1e0f7e7e89a81f42)